# Process select option data into database dynamically {EDITED}

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-select

I have a form that contain select option where user can add row and data in the select option comes from the database. The add row button function is working, the issue now is to store the drop down rows when clicked add button into the database.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

 var rowNum = 0;
 function addR(btn){

      rowNum ++;

     var select_val = $('#my_select').val();
     $.post("test2.php",{select_val:select_val},function(data){
     $(btn).closest('table').append(data);    

     }); 


 }

</script>
```

The test2.php code to get the data

```
$qty = mysql_query("SELECT * from courses where course_department = '10'")or die(mysql_error());

echo '<tr><td><select id="my_select">';


while($ft = mysql_fetch_assoc($qty)){
    echo'<option value="'.$ft["course_id"].'">'.$ft["course_id"].'</option>';

}

echo '</select></td></tr>';
```

The test1.php code that process the select option

```
 $check = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student_course(matric_no, session, teacher_id, course_id, semester) VALUES('$matric', '2015', '147', '".$_POST['my_select']."'', '$semester')") or die(mysql_error(). 'Cannot connect');

     if($check){
         echo 'Uploaded';
     }else{
         echo 'not uploaded';
     }

<td>
<button type="button" onClick="addR(this)">Add Courses</button>
</td></tr></table>
```

I want to be able to process all add rows into the database at the same time. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where's the code for the INSERT then? or is this a "show me, code it for me" type of question? if so, it's both too broad and unclear.

Comment: What is the `for` loop in test2.php meant to do? It seems pretty useless right now.

Comment: @RST I have edited the question. Now the database query is there.

Comment: I was debugging but it is removed now.. @Fred -ii-